# DOM Exception 8 Error - Leaflet w/ Clustering

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I currently have a Leaflet map that pulls in data from a GeoJSON file and clusters it, like so:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    showCoverageOnHover: true,
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true  
});

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(thefts, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.bike_value);
    }
});

markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
map.addLayer(markers);
map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

The middle piece is what's giving me some trouble:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(thefts, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.bike_value);
    }
});
```

Every time I try to click on a popup, I get a console error that says **Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8**. Th error stack looks like this:

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 leaflet.js:7
    o.Popup.o.Class.extend.onRemove leaflet.js:7
    o.Map.o.Class.extend.removeLayer leaflet.js:6
    o.Map.include.closePopup leaflet.js:7
    o.Popup.o.Class.extend._close leaflet.js:7
    o.Marker.include.closePopup leaflet.js:7
    o.Marker.include.togglePopup leaflet.js:7
    o.Mixin.Events.fireEvent leaflet.js:6
    o.Marker.o.Class.extend._onMouseClick leaflet.js:7
    t.(anonymous function).s
```

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this? I know there have been other questions related to DOM Exception 8, but I couldn't find anything that pertains to what I'm doing.

Comment: is this from running as a file in your browser, or with a server

Comment: In my browser. No backend at this time.

Comment: I have had a `DOM Exception 8` error in a variety of cases and every one of them has been solved by putting the site online.

Comment: I put it online and still no dice.